# Can't select elements with scrapy-splash

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using this code, to extract text in specific link class. I can select one element of that class `.extract_first()` and I coudn't with all the elements of the same class, I want to be able to select them all and store them in a list. There is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes4"

    start_urls = ["https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        # I can select first element of class
        '''yield{ 
            'name': response.css(".shelfProductTile-descriptionLink::text").extract_first()
            }'''

        # But not all the elements of the same class
        a= response.css(".shelfProductTile-descriptionLink::text").extract()
        print ('list lengh is : ' + str(len(a)))   # OUTPUT  : 0
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be using scrapy_splash for this? Your yield statement looks like regular scrapy code, not scrapy_splash. If what you're scraping from is just html (not javascript) then you don't need scrapy_splash.

Comment: The class I want to print is loaded dynamically from JS

Comment: Are you waiting long enough?

Comment: Normally scrapy splash requires an 'endpoint' and 'args' argument with SplashRequest function, that's why I was saying it looks like regular scrapy code.